# How to pass argument set of useReducer() hook?

Tags: reactjs

I am learning react, I am trying to use `useReducer()` and make it do two task based on some state. My `App.js` look like below. When I click button, the values are not passed to `setCounterValue`. What is wrong here?

```js
import "./styles.css";

import { useReducer } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [counterValue, setCounterValue] = useReducer(
    (a) => (a[1] ? [a[0] + 1, a[1]] : [a[0] - 2, a[1]]), //
    [1, false] // counter and a flag to inc/dec
  );
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>
        Start editing to see [{counterValue[0]}, {counterValue[1].toString()}]
        magic happen!!
      </h2>
      <button onClick={() => setCounterValue([1, true])}>Inc</button>
      <button onClick={() => setCounterValue()}>Dec</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You're missing the second argument of the `useReducer` callback: the `action`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Nick and Sahil, based on your responses I modified the code and it works. I was missing 2nd argument in my reducer functions, that's understood.

**But in 4th last line `<button onClick={() => setCounterValue(false)}>Dec</button>`, I am passing only one argument to `setCounterValue`, how does it get passed as 2nd argument `b` in my reducer function?**

```js
import "./styles.css";

import { useReducer } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [counterValue, setCounterValue] = useReducer(
    (a, b) => (b ? a + 1 : a - 1), // b is T/F, passed from setCounterValue
    1 // counter
  );
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see {counterValue} magic happen!!</h2>
      <button onClick={() => setCounterValue(true)}>Inc</button>
      <button onClick={() => setCounterValue(false)}>Dec</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use that one it works perfectly !

```
const initialState = {count: 0};

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'increment':
      return {count: state.count + 1};
    case 'decrement':
      return {count: state.count - 1};
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}

function Counter() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  return (
    <>
      Count: {state.count}
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'decrement'})}>-</button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({type: 'increment'})}>+</button>
    </>
  );
}
```